# Async await not working as I expected on emitter

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I'm trying to learn by building a simple game with html and Js, using Nodejs and mongoose on the backend. It is like a grid where you can click to move around and you have to get to the treasure. When you click in the treasure tile, the backend gets the wincode from Mongodb and send it to the front.

miApp.allGames is an array where I store a "currentUserInfoMov" obcject with the info for every game currently being played, one for browser using local storage, that is working fine.

My problem is that movementsEmitter don't wait until it gets the code from Mongodb. In my console I can see the console.logs in this order:

1.you win!
2. Sent to front 
3. Emitter finished

```
routerApi.post("/clicked", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    miApp.movementsEmitter.emit("playerWantToMove", req.body, grid);
    const currentUserInfoMov = miApp.allGames.filter(x => x.Id == req.body.id)[0];
    res.send(currentUserInfoMov);
    console.log("Sent to Front");

  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)  
  }
})
```

---

On the movementsEmitter:

```
movementsEmitter.on("playerWantToMove", async (tileClickedAndId, grid) => {

...more code here working fine...

 if (playerDestiny == treasureTile) {
  console.log("you win!");
  const bottle = await Bottles.findById(BOTTLEID);
  currentUserInfoMov.winCode = bottle.codeToWin;     
  TakeBottle();
  console.log("Emitter finished");
     
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, everything is happening as expected.

1. you are emitting the `playerWantToMove` event
2. The `on` event handler is called => and `console.log("you win!")` is called
3. You await a request to Bottles. This is an asynchronous request and gets moved to the job queue, until the call stack is empty.
4. The code then the continues to execute your `.post` block => and `console.log('sent to front')` is called
5. the call stack is now empty, so the code below the `awaited` line runs => and console.log(`Emitter finished`) is called

So you need to reorder your code a bit. If you want to execute in a different order, just move the `emit` to after `res.send`. My guess though, is that `takeBottle` updates the DB and therefore the response you are sending to the front end. You can try to `await` the emitted event (if your event emitter allows that. `await miApp.movementsEmitter.emit("playerWantToMove", ...)`. The other option is update the event handler to call `res.send()` within that, after `TakeBottle()` is called

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't await the my movementsEmitter. I will try to call res.send() inside my movementsEmitter.